# Is it possible to access backend fields from my own field type?

Tags: plugin-development, entry, custom-fieldtype

I'm trying to access the value of an asset field in a backend entry form from my plugins own field type.

At the moment it's looking like the following:

```
public function prepValue($value)
{
    $filename = "path/to/csv";

    if( ($handle = fopen( $filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $rowCounter = 0;
        while (($rowData = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            if( 0 === $rowCounter) {
                $headerRecord = $rowData;
            } else {
                foreach( $rowData as $key => $val) {
                    $value[ $rowCounter - 1][ $headerRecord[ $key] ] = $val;  
                }
            }
            $rowCounter++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

All of the csv values are mapped to a table column of the same field type:

```
public function getInputHtml($name, $value)
{   
    $id = 'test';
    $cols = array(
        'col_1' => array(
            'heading' => 'Col 1',
            'type'    => 'singleline',
        ),
        'col_2'   => array(
            'heading' => 'Col 2',
            'type'    => 'singleline'
        ),
        'col_3'   => array(
            'heading' => 'Col 3',
            'type'    => 'number'
        ),
        'col_4'   => array(
            'heading' => 'Col 4',
            'type'    => 'number'
        ),
        'col_5'   => array(
            'heading' => 'Col 5',
            'type'    => 'singleline'
        ),
        'col_6'   => array(
            'heading' => 'Col 6',
            'type'    => 'singleline',
        ),
    );

    return craft()->templates->render('csvImport/csvimport', array(
        'name'  => $name,
        'value' => $value,
        'id'    => $id,
        'cols'  => $cols,

    ));
}
```

I would like to fill $filename dynamically with the value of an asset field in the same entry backend form. Is this possible?

//EDIT:

Ok I solved the above problem by just changing the prepValue() to the prepValueFromPost()-Function. I now am able to access every piece of data I want to through the post array.

Comment: When do you need the value? Do you need it before saving the entry or do you need it as soon as the other field's value changes?

Comment: It would be enough to have it when the save button is clicked. So in the "onBeforeSave" function for example (which never seems to be called for whatever reasons...).